# Rasa core custom template

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I want to create a custom templates on the domain.yml file

Example domain.yml

```
utter_ask_cards
    - header: Heading1
      image: <image url>
      buttons:
          - title: button_name1
            payload: button1
          - title: button_name2
            payload: button2
```

Answer (score 1):

In Rasa there are 4 types of responses possible

- Text  - Simple text message
- Button  - Button with text and button texts. I don't think you can mix this with image
- Image - Image as an attachment
- Elements - This is what you can explore for custom message.

You can try something like this-

`utter_ask_cards:
    - text: " Heading1"
      buttons: 
      - title: "button_name1"
        payload: "button1"
      - title: "button_name2"
        payload: "button2"`

Hope this answered your question.